# how do I know what is the source of Bus error in Python?

Tags: python, gdb

I am having a Bus error in a Python script.

I could believe there is some issue with the memory there, but I don't know exactly what the source is.

I would expect it to be possible somehow to trace the line of Python code where this happens (even without a full stack).

It does say "core dumped", but no core is dumped, and I am not sure if Python core dumps can easily be used with gdb or the like to trace the line of code where the error happened.

What are my options? The error at the moment is cryptic in the sense that I don't know where the faulty memory access happens or why.

(I should mention that I did try to investigate for answers online before asking this, but didn't find anything useful. Just small pieces of "I am stuck" kind of things. I am guessing this error is very rare.)

EDIT:

$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.12

Yes, I am using C/C++ libraries, I believe, like numpy, copy (not sure if it is C/C++), torch.

I am not sure it is a good idea to post the code here, as it is quite a long .py file, and I am not sure exactly where the code gives that error, especially without a core dump actually being written to the disk.

I will mention that there are several parts where I am slightly concerned about unnecessary memory use that accumulates (this part is called a lot):

This loop:

```
for key in self.parameters.keys():
            new = self.parameters[key]['x'].parameter
            self.parser.parameters[key]['x'].parameter = new.detach().clone()
```

Comment: You mind posting your code?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you got a bus error with pure Python. Are custom (C/C++) libraries involved? We need to see the code that causes this. Also, what Python version?

Comment: Can you install the version of python with debugging aids? It may be provided by your distro if you're running GNU/Linux, or you can easily build Python from source using the `./configure --with-pydebug` flag. There will be a `python-gdb.py` file full of extensions for GDB such as `py-bt`.